# Need help to identify usb cable

Tags: hard-drive, usb, cable

Below is my Seagate 9SD2A6-500's USB2 port and cable, which had oxidative damage, so I want to buy a replacement cable.

What is the name of this cable type and would a USB3 cable be backwards compatible with a USB2 HDD port? Is this cable what I'm looking for: [Storite USB2 A to Mini 5pin B Cable](https://www.amazon.in/Storite-USB-2-0-Mini-External/dp/B00GGGOYDG)

[image: USB Cable]
[image: HDD Port]

Comment: [Cabling - an overview | Seagate Support UK](https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/kb/cabling-an-overview-205479en/)

Comment: You can get those in any electronic store or electronic section of a stationery Big Box store. Make sure it was just the cable that oxidized. That would be unusual.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard [USB A to mini B cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware).

[Something like this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/AmazonBasics-Male-Mini-B-Cable-Feet/dp/B00NH11N5A/ref=asc_df_B00NH11N5A/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=205231791255&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=9794281009314159207&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9046387&hvtargid=pla-330035844136&psc=1&th=1&psc=1#ace-4127440567) would work fine.

Comment: Would new cable have to be 2.0 as well or would usb 3.0 cable be backwards compatible to USB 2.0 hdd?

Comment: Cables are normally backwards compatible.

Comment: The USB 2.0 interface would be the bottleneck - so using a USB 3.0 cable would provide no benefit here.

Comment: I don't think you'll find any mini-B cables compatible with USB 3.0, that standard was superseded by micro-B long time ago.